# Code generation different than expected

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm following the `Programming Phoenix` book to build the given Rumbl application. My problem has to do with the chapter where we use generators to create lot of functionality automatically. The command used was:

```
$ mix phoenix.gen.html Video videos user_id:references:users url:string title:string description:text
```

The problem now is that is that at several places, there's difference between the code given in the book and what I'm getting. One good example is the `web/models/video.ex` module. The code I ended up with is:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Video do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "videos" do
    field :url, :string
    field :title, :string
    field :description, :string
    belongs_to :user, Rumbl.User

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:url, :title, :description])
    |> validate_required([:url, :title, :description])
  end
end
```

whereas in the book, the `changeset` function is given as:

```
@required_fields ~w(url title description)
@optional_fields ~w()

def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
```

(please excuse typos in the latter snippet; I had to type it by hand)

I don't understand why this difference is there. Could it be because of version differences? And more importantly, what does this difference mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a version difference. Phoenix 1.2 switched to using Ecto 2.0, which deprecated the 4 arity version of `Ecto.Changeset.cast` in favor of the 3 arity one + a call to `Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3`. Ecto 2.0 also depracated passing `:empty` to `cast`. All this and some more changes are documented in [the changelog](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/a615dd05d5fcad31383d9edeb3bf77706cd9b608/CHANGELOG.md#revamped-changesets):

> ### Highlights
>
> #### Revamped changesets
>
> Due to feedback, we have made three important changes to changesets:
>
> 1. `changeset.model` has been renamed to `changeset.data` (we no longer have "models" in Ecto)
> 2. Passing required and optional fields to `cast/4` is deprecated in favor of `cast/3` and `validate_required/3`
> 3. The `:empty` atom in `cast(source, :empty, required, optional)` has been deprecated, please use an empty map or `:invalid` instead
>
> To summarize those changes, instead of:
>
> ```
> def changeset(user, params \\ :empty) do
>   user
>   |> cast(params, [:name], [:age])
> end
> ```
>
> One should write:
>
> ```
> def changeset(user, params \\ %{}) do
>   user
>   |> cast(params, [:name, :age])
>   |> validate_required([:name])
> end
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you again, good sir! May I say these version differences are *extremely* annoying? :-)

Comment: Yep, definitely very annoying when you're just learning stuff. I hope PragProg releases an updated version of the book soon.